# How do I format my Graph request to post multiple messages in Teams?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I would like to post several messages with one Graph request only.
My request looks like this :

```
{
    "body": {
        "content": "Hello World"
    }
}
```

I just want to post a lot of different messages. I don't know if I should do a table or something like that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course each message itself needs to be an individual request, but it's possible to make multiple requests in a single call, using Batching. Please see here for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/batch-requests?tabs=csharp

Comment: @Hauften - Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?

Comment: I guess that is the option I will go for, yes. Thanks.